# Runtime error in python (Hacker-rank practice question)

Tags: python, runtime

So i'm doing this hacker-rank question and i'm getting runtime errors however when I run it on my IDE it works perfectly how can I optimize this code?

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def solve(s):
    list(s)
    x, y = map(str.capitalize, s.split(' '))
    return ' '.join([x, y])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    result = solve(s)

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: What runtime error? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Xilpex IDK on the website it just says ```Runtime Error```

Comment: Which website are you using? It should elaborate. Could you should the stack trace?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/capitalize/problem this is the problem I was working on

Comment: This is most likely because "OUTPUT_PATH" isn't there.

Comment: Its just for the website, on my IDE i replaced it with a print statement I just need to optimize it so it works on the website

Comment: I agree with @Xilpex, maybe the problem is in the OUTPUT_PATH, furthermore, `..open(os.environ...`  looks needless, try just print(result)

Comment: Yes, the compiler error says: `Runtime Error`, but below that appears `Error (stderr)`. That would explain the reason of the error.